# Understanding the output of a fixed-effects-model in R

Tags: r, regression, time-series, plm, diversity

I am researching whether female representation changes the innovation output of companies. I have panel data of 30 companies over 10 years and "diversity, sales, r&dbudget, #employees" as my independent variables and "# of product launches/year" as my dependent variable.

I have found out that I need to use a panel data model and pooled ols is not suitable because it just throws all values in one bin. After conducting a hausman-test I am now using a fixed-effects-model in R.

Here is where the confusion begins. The R-Output looks like this:

```
Coefficients :
      Estimate  Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)  
X1 -2.5395e-02  6.7500e-02 -0.3762  0.70721  
X2  3.4111e-09  9.0524e-09  0.3768  0.70677  
X3 -2.2587e-08  9.5763e-08 -0.2359  0.81381  
X4  2.3481e-04  9.9681e-05  2.3556  0.01961 *
X5  2.2199e+00  1.5280e+00  1.4528  0.14808  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    2320.4
Residual Sum of Squares: 2231
R-Squared:      0.038532
Adj. R-Squared: -0.14934
```

But when I remove one variable from the mix, it comes out like this:

```
Coefficients :
      Estimate  Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)  
X1 -7.2331e-02  5.9454e-02 -1.2166  0.22540  
X2  3.4415e-09  9.0811e-09  0.3790  0.70516  
X3 -1.5963e-08  9.5957e-08 -0.1664  0.86807  
X4  1.8957e-04  9.4993e-05  1.9956  0.04753 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    2320.4
Residual Sum of Squares: 2258.1
R-Squared:      0.026869
Adj. R-Squared: -0.15664
```

Why do all values change when I remove a single independent variable? Is this only due to the fact that now one possible explanantion is missing and the model has to account for that ?

Also, is my interpretation of the first output correct when I state that:

-No independent varaible has significant impact.

-X4 is still "okay" in terms of significance.

-There is a slightly positive relationship between my independent variables and 
dependent variable, although it's not significant.

Comment: Please note that the question is not confined to panel models / the `plm` package, rather it applies to linear regression in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do all values change when I remove a single independent variable? Is this only due to the fact that now one possible explanantion is missing and the model has to account for that ?

The reason that the estimates change when the model changes is because inclusion/exclusion of IV's modify how much variation in your DV can be explained by variation in each IV. As @Rebecca said, your first model has a higher $R^2$ than your second, which implies that inclusion of X5 explains variance in your DV. This however is expected, you will never lose explained variance through inclusion of coefficients. The question is, does the amount of explained variance significantly increase between model 1 and model 2. This can assessed via:

`anova(model1, model2)`

Where `model1` and `model2` are defined fixed effects models.

> Also, is my interpretation of the first output correct when I state that:
>
> -No independent varaible has significant impact.

This depends on the alpha level of your investigation. If $\alpha = .05$, `X4` is a significant predictor in both of your models.

> -X4 is still "okay" in terms of significance.

See above, it is considered statistically significant insofar that it's *p*-value is below your alpha threshold.

> -There is a slightly positive relationship between my independent variables and dependent variable, although it's not significant.

This is tricky: Each of them, Yes and No. Are your variables continuous or categorical, if the former then `X1` and `X3` are negative and the others are positive.

Comment: Ahhh, I see my mistake. I thought the r-significance-grouping with star codes (*, **, ***) was the respective alpha...which in retrospect makes no sense at all. 

X4 is the amount of employees in my model. I should probably remove that from the model, if I want to look for the effects of female representation?

Comment: It's hard to say. I see in your description you explain X1 - X4, but no mention is made of X5. In building an appropriate model for your research goal you should consider: "What factors could potentially influence innovation output". IMO, I retain the number of employees as it would be rational to assume that the number of people you have would influence said output.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that when your independent variables change in the model, all values will change. I don't know why you removed X5, but if X5 was removed, the new model has to account for that. Actually, in your case, the first model is better than the second model. You can look at R2 or adjusted R2, they are bigger in the first model. It means that the first model explains more variation in your dependent variable. Your second model has more missing information. For me, it is not reasonable to remove X5.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your predictors are correlated. If predictors were orthogonal (that is, uncorrelated) removing one of them wouldn't change the parameters or the significance of the remaining ones. The extreme case of higly correlated predictors is [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity).